# Django Form Widgets SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call

Tags: python, django, widget

I'm trying form widgets and I coded this class in my `forms.py`:

```
class RawProductForm(forms.Form):
    title       = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder: "Your title"}))
    description = forms.CharField(
                                required= False, 
                                widget=forms.Textarea(
                                    attrs={
                                        "class": "new-class-name two",
                                        "id": "my-id-for-textarea",
                                        "rows": 100,
                                        "cols": 20
                                    }
                                        )
                                )
    price       = forms.DecimalField(initial=199.99)
```

But I'm getting an error which I do not know how to solve:

```
line 16
    title       = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder: "Your title"}))
                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```

Comment: I'm calling the function in my `views.py` as follows: 
`from .forms import ProductForm, RawProductForm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a syntax issue.
You're missing some " after `placeholder`.

Your code should look like this :

```
widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Your title"})
```